# This どうして doesn't mean "why", does it?

Tags: grammar

For full context, see here:
https://www.docdroid.net/ipTEvqI/1.pdf

The sentence in question is from もんだい number 2, line 1 (おんな):
あるテレビ会社が、夫は妻に、妻は夫に**どうして**ほしいと思っているかアンケート調査をしました。

I marked it in bold. Considering the context of the full text, where we are told what husbands wish to have done by their wifes and vice versa, I think this "how (to) do" in the sense of "what to do". 
Therefore, I'd translate the sentence as follows:

"Some TV-Company did an investigation (here: evaluation?) of a survey/questionnaire about what husbands want their wifes to do (for them) and what wifes want their husbands do (for them)."

Comment: maybe it could be どう＋してほしい instead of どうして＋ほしい. I'm not sure, though

Comment: @FelipeOliveira you should expand this into an answer, as that's correct

Comment: @psosuna The problem is that I came to that conclusion based on the translation, but pratically i'm not sure how to tell the difference between どう＋してほしい and どうして（そのことが）ほしい？which I guess could be the same as なんで（そのことが）ほしい？

Comment: @Felipe Oliveira I think どう ＋ してほしい means "What do you want me to do?" and どうして ＋ ほしい means " Why do you want that?".

Comment: @YuuichiTam I agree, my doubt is not really the meaning of them, but how to recognize one apart from the other in a sentence, if it's just by context or not

Comment: At least in the context of this question, it makes far more sense to ask what a partner wants the other to do, than why someone wants their partner. In that sense, you could also attempt supplanting どうしてほしい with どうすればいい and if the sentence still makes sense it is likely the context refers to どう＋してほしい and not どうして＋ほしい

Comment: 「どう」 often translates to "what" in English, as in **どう**したんですか？ "*What* happened? / *What*'s the matter?" **どう**しよう！ "*What* should I do!?" **どう**思いますか？ "*What* do you think?" -- hence, **どう**してほしいですか？ "*What* do you want (them) to do?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 日本語

> (0) あるテレビ会社が、夫は妻に、妻は夫に**どうして**ほしいと思っているかアンケート調査をしました。

### 回答その１

> This どうして doesn't mean “why”, does it?

(0) は複雑な文章なので、回答その１を検討するために (0) を少し簡単にすると (1) になる。

> (1) 夫は妻に**どうして**ほしいと思っているか、あるテレビ会社が調査をした。
> (2) 夫は妻に**なぜ**ほしいと思っているか、あるテレビ会社が調査をした。

ここで、(1) の「どうして」が "why" なら、"どうして" は、"何故｛なぜ｝" に置き換えられ (2) に書き換えることができる。(2) を見ると他動詞「ほしい」の目的語がないことに気づく。そこで目的語として something の代わりに「新しい家」を登場させると、(3) になる。

> (3) 夫は妻にどうして**新しい家**がほしいと思っているか、あるテレビ会社が調査をした。
> (4) どうして新しい家がほしいと思っているか夫は妻に**たずねた**。
> (5) どうして新しい家がほしいと思っているか夫は妻にたずねた**ことを**あるテレビ会社が調査をした。

新しくできた (3) では、「夫」と「妻」と「テレビ会社」との関係が良く分からない。そこで、(3) から「テレビ会社」を外して自然な日本語の文をつくると (4) になる。(4) に対して「テレビ会社」を登場さすと、例えば (5) のようになる。(5) は自然な日本語の文である。

(1) の中の「どうして」を "why" と解釈すると (5) のような日本語である必要があり、(1) を (5) にするために、いくつかの変更が必要であった。従って、(1) の「どうして」を "why" と解釈することは無理である。同様に、(0) の「どうして」も "why" という意味を持たせることは無理であり、間違いである。

## English

> (0) あるテレビ会社が、夫は妻に、妻は夫に**どうして**ほしいと思っているかアンケート調査をしました。

### Answer Part 1

> This どうして doesn't mean “why”, does it?

Since the sentence (0) is a little complicated, if (0) is made a little easier in order to examine the answer for Answer Part 1, it becomes (1).

> (1) 夫は妻に**どうして**ほしいと思っているか、あるテレビ会社が調査をした。
> (2) 夫は妻に**なぜ**ほしいと思っているか、あるテレビ会社が調査をした。

Here, if "どうして" in sentence (1) is meant "why", the "どうして" could be replaced with "何故｛なぜ｝", then (1) could be rewritten to sentence (2). When I peruse the sentence (2), I notice that there is no object for the transitive verb "ほしい". Then, letting "新しい家 *a new house*" exist as an object instead of "something", it becomes sentence (3).

> (3) 夫は妻にどうして**新しい家**がほしいと思っているか、あるテレビ会社が調査をした。
> (4) どうして新しい家がほしいと思っているか夫は妻に**たずねた**。
> (5) どうして新しい家がほしいと思っているか夫は妻にたずねた**ことを**あるテレビ会社が調査をした。

In the new sentence (3), the relationship between "夫 *husband*", "妻 *wife*" and "テレビ会社 *TV company*" isn't clear. So, if you omit the part including "テレビ会社" from (3) and create a natural Japanese sentence, it becomes a sentence like (4). If you add the omitted part including "テレビ会社" properly to the sentence (4), it will become like sentence (5). I can say (5) is also a natural Japanese sentence.

If you interpret "どうして" in (1) as "why", it is necessary to prepare a natural Japanese like (5); and in order to get (5), some changes were necessary to (1) as was explained above. Therefore, it is impossible to interpret "どうして" in (1) as "why". Likewise, it is impossible to understand the meaning of "どうして" in (0) as "why".

In conclusion, I can say that it is incorrect to interpret "どうして" in (0) as "why".

Answer (score 3):

You're correct!

> あるテレビ会社が、夫は妻に、妻は夫に**どうしてほしい**と思っているかアンケート調査をしました。

=夫は妻に、妻は夫に、**どのように　して　ほしい**　と思っているか　アンケート調査をしました。

In this context, **どう＝how=どのように**.

As Japanese sentences don't put spaces between words, you should guess the meaning by the interpretation of the context and background. Confusions may occur because of the writing system of the Japanese language, as you mentioned.

For example,

> 電気自動車の人気が急激に高まっており生産が追いつかず、購入希望者は何ヶ月も予約順番待ちの状態です。購入希望者に**どうしてほしい**と思っているか、アンケート調査をしました。

＝　**なぜ、「欲しい」**　と思っているか or **どのようにメーカーに対応して欲しい**と思っているか

In this context, どうして can mean "why,"  while the other interpretation, "what do they want?", can be possible as well.

Comment: Thanks! :) Your answer has helped a lot, I definitely would have given your answer the "check", but the answer of mackygoo was so ridiculously  detailed (and bilingual Oo) I gave it hers/his instead! Still, again, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Oh, thank you for your reply. I appreciate your 思いやり or ご配慮. I think mackygoo's answer is an awesome one, and vote +1. Have a nice weekend! :)